How is the namespace able to communicate with eth0 without NAT here
I was following this tutorial https://github.com/faysalmehedi/linux-network-namespaces-hands-on
I had to use this command so that our ns1 namespace can talk to eth0, where 192.168.1.1 is the IP address of the bridge created, and ceth0 is the veth connected to the ns1
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ip route add default via 192.168.1.1

It created this entry on the routing table for ns1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ceth0

table:
sudo ip netns exec ns1 route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ceth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ceth0

For the destination 0.0.0.0, it has to go through the gateway, so here the bridge is acting like a gateway.
So now if we ping the eth0 (172.31.13.55) from ns1 namespace, it works as expected
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ping 172.31.13.55
64 bytes from 172.31.13.55: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.13.55: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms

But when we ping the outside internet, it'll say Unreachable
sudo ip netns exec ns1 ping 8.8.8.8
I'm confused why there is no NAT or IP forwarding when talking to eth0
How does it know its not the outside internet, it's from different subnet than the existing namespace and bridge
what distinguishes 8.8.8.8 and eth0 IP
and the routing table only had 0.0.0.0 as destination which should be applicable for both these IPs

Do you mean like 172.31.13.55 is the IP assigned on eth0? Or is it another host in the network that eth0 is connected to?

@TomYan 172.31.13.55 is the IP assigned to the eth0

Well, then it's normal. The packet "stops" / is "processed" at the default namespace. Since there's a route to 192.168.1.x there, no NAT ia required. (It is only required when it is "processed" on some other host where an appropriate route doesn't exist.) It's kinda like you are ping'ing 192.168.1.1.
